# Elisp construct

Tags: list, quote

What is this construct in `elisp` ?

```
'( ("approx" "approximately")  ("appt" "appointment")
     ("apt" "apartment")         ("dept" "department")
     ("est" "established")       ("misc" "miscellaneous")
     ("no" "number")             ("tel" "telephone")
     ("temp" "temperature")      ("vs" "versus") )
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list. In emacs-lisp, lists can be created using `'(...)`. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lists.html) is more information about them.

Comment: A list of lists then ?

Comment: Yes, it is a list of lists.